# Fixed positioned navigation with horizontal scrolling (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently developing a website that has a 'sticky' navigation bar when it reaches the top of the page, so that the navigation links are always in view of the user. Before the navigation bar's positioning is changed to 'fixed' by jQuery, you are able to horizontally scroll with the rest of the page however when it is switched to fixed, you can't scroll it to see all of the links.

How can I make it so that the navigation is fixed to the top of the page after scrolling a certain amount of pixels, yet also allow it to scroll horizontally with the rest of the page?

**Relevant CSS:**

```
.navigation {
   position:relative;
    background-color:#4F4F4F;
    width:100%;
    min-width:980px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .4);
    z-index:10;
    overflow-x:visible;
    height:auto;
}

.navigation-scrolled {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    overflow-x:visible; 
}
```

**jQuery for switching styles (fixed)**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var nav = $(".navigation");

    if($(this).scrollTop() > 194) {

        nav.addClass("navigation-scrolled");
        $("#top").hide();
        $(":1.container").fadeToggle(400);

    } else {

        nav.removeClass("navigation-scrolled");
        $("#top").show();

    }

});
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a header that stays "stuck" to the top of the page, but once you have scrolled a certain distance, it's able to scroll off the screen?

Comment: I've created a navigation bar that is first relative positioned just below the logo and login at the top of the page, then when the user scrolls down 194 pixels the navigation bar sticks to the top of the page with 'position:fixed'. the problem is that with the position fixed, the navigation bar won't scroll horizontally when the user resizes their window @vihan1086

Comment: Can you please provide your html so we can see what you are trying to do.  If possible, can you please provide a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/.